# How can I delete email trigger by "Send email with options" in MS Flow?

Tags: email, delete, ms-flow, sp-online

I am using "send with options" action in MS Flow. It sent a new email with buttons.

[image]

My requirement is, when I click on any button, whether Paid or Unpaid, the email sent via "send with options" should also get deleted automatically.

I do not want to keep those emails in my inbox so can I delete those emails also automatically?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you mean like the meeting invites?

Comment: When we send an email using "Send email with Options" action in MS Flow, it sends an email with buttons, I just want to delete those email when I clicked on the button that is generated via "Send email with options" action in MS flow.

Comment: What's your mail server?

Comment: What mail server? I am using SharePoint Online and MS Flow and outlook 365

Comment: I guess the max you can do is delete the email from sent box. Try this https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/Get-Email-Message-ID-and-Delete-from-Sent-Box/td-p/279745